# Defining Variables Prior to use in TCL

Tags: variables, tcl

I'm brand new to TCL, and am trying to wrap my brain around all the usages of "", {}, and [] that it uses.  Something I'm used to doing in other languages is defining my variables prior to use, at the beginning of the application.  The below code works:

```
puts "Please enter an integer of choice to be added: "
flush stdout
gets stdin intAnswer

puts "Please enter a second integer of choice to be added: "
flush stdout
gets stdin intAnswerTwo

puts "Please enter a third integer of choice to be added: "
flush stdout
gets stdin intAnswerThree

puts "The total of the three integers is: [expr $intAnswer + $intAnswerTwo + $intAnswerThree]"
```

What I'm wanting to do is define the variables prior to use.  As such:

```
set intAnswer 0
set intAnswerTwo 0
set intAnswerThree 0
set intTotal 0
```

This code, placed at the beginning, doesn't work with the rest of the code.  What am I missing?

Comment: What does "doesn't work with the rest of the code" mean?  Putting those four lines at the top of the existing code doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Perhaps it's because it's late, I don't know.  I reinserted the variable sets into the code and it worked.  This can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks absolutely fine to me, though `[expr {$intAnswer + $intAnswerTwo + $intAnswerThree}]` would be better (as it stops potential reinterpretation of the variables' contents, which would be both a safety and performance issue).

However, if you really want to have integers from the user, you need to *validate* their input. This is most easily done by writing a procedure to do the job so you can reuse it (i.e., you *refactor* the code to get a value so you can use a more sophisticated version and get it right *once*):

```
proc getIntFromUser {message} {
    # Loop forever (until we [exit] or [return $response])
    while true {
        puts $message
        flush stdout
        set response [gets stdin]
        # Important to check for EOF...
        if {[eof stdin]} {
            exit
        }
        # The validator (-strict is needed for ugly historical reasons)
        if {[string is integer -strict $response]} {
            return $response
        }
        # Not an integer, so moan about it
        puts "\"$response\" is not an integer!"
    }
}
```

Now you have that procedure, the rest of your code can become:

```
set intAnswer      [getIntFromUser "Please enter an integer of choice to be added: "]
set intAnswerTwo   [getIntFromUser "Please enter a second integer of choice to be added: "]
set intAnswerThree [getIntFromUser "Please enter a third integer of choice to be added: "]

puts "The total of the three integers is: [expr {$intAnswer + $intAnswerTwo + $intAnswerThree}]"
```

The art of writing good Tcl code (or good code in pretty much any other language) is knowing what are the good points to refactor. A good starting point is “if you do it twice or more, do it once and share”. It's doubly good if you can give the procedure a good name and clear interface, a clear indication that you've got it right. Indeed, you could also go for:

```
set total [expr {
    [getIntFromUser "Please enter an integer of choice to be added: "] +
    [getIntFromUser "Please enter a second integer of choice to be added: "] +
    [getIntFromUser "Please enter a third integer of choice to be added: "]
}]

puts "The total of the three integers is: $total"
```

The results observed by the user will be identical.

Comment: The other thing to be aware of is that all Tcl variables in procedures are local by default. If you want to use global variables, you should declare what variables you're doing this with using the `global` command at the top of your procedure.

Comment: Thanks for this, there was a portion of additional code I had added into the program last night that used a procedure to receive input with an if/elseif statement that wasn't returning an input value correctly.  This helps a good deal.